# Join tables in order

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's my say, I have two tables PTO_CONTROL and RUTA_PTO, 
I try join this tables only by the FK_PTO that they 
share in the order that provide the PTO_CONTROL table. 
The problem until now is that always get the first 
register that find in the search, obtaining repeated values. 
How I can create the sql instruction to fix this issue? Thanks.

```
TABLE PTO_CONTROL
ID  FK_PTO  NUM     HORA
55  122     566     5:02        
56  104     568     5:16
57  114     572     5:38
58  104     573     6:12
59  110     577     6:28
60  122     582     6:45

TABLE RUTA_PTO
ID  FK_RUTA FK_PTO  TIEMPO
15  56      122     0
16  56      104     12
17  56      114     22
18  56      104     32
19  56      121     40
20  56      110     45
21  56      122     55

JOIN TABLE / VALUES EXPECTED
FK_PTO  NUM HORA TIEMPO
122     566 5:02 0
104     568 5:16 12
114     572 5:38 22
104     573 6:12 32
110     577 6:28 45
122     582 6:45 55
```

The DML and sql instruction can be,

```
    CREATE TABLE pto (
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
     NOMBRE VARCHAR(32)
    );

    CREATE TABLE ruta (
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
     NOMBRE VARCHAR(32)
    );

    CREATE TABLE ruta_pto (
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
     FK_RUTA INT NOT NULL,
     FK_PTO INT NOT NULL,
     TIEMPO INT,
     CONSTRAINT FK_RUTA_PTO_PTO
      FOREIGN KEY (FK_PTO)
      REFERENCES pto (ID)
     CONSTRAINT FK_RUTA_PTO_RUTA
      FOREIGN KEY (FK_RUTA)
      REFERENCES ruta (ID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE pto_control (
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
     FK_PTO INT NOT NULL,
     NUM INT,
     HORA TIME,
     CONSTRAINT FK_PTO_CONTROL_PTO
      FOREIGN KEY (FK_PTO)
      REFERENCES pto (ID)
    );

    SELECT
     pc.FK_PTO,
     pc.NUM,
     pc.HORA,
     rp.TIEMPO
    FROM pto_control AS pc
    INNER JOIN ruta_pto AS rp ON
     pc.FK_PTO = rp.FK_PTO AND rp.FK_RUTA = 56
    INNER JOIN pto AS p ON
     pc.FK_PTO = p.ID;

    and the wrong result that obtain is

    FK_PTO  NUM HORA TIEMPO
    122     566 5:02 0
    104     568 5:16 12
    114     572 5:38 22
    104     568 5:16 12
    110     577 6:28 45
    122     566 5:02 0
```

Comment: I can't understand your question.  Maybe give us the DDL of the 2 tables and the SQL query you are attempting to use to "join" the tables.  The "Join Table" you speak of isn't something I am familiar with.  Usually you hear the phrase "join" in a relational database in the context of a SQL Query not Table DDL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement group ranking for both tables. That can be done with these queries:

```
select c1.*, count(*) as rank
from PTO_CONTROL c1
join PTO_CONTROL c2
  on  c2.FK_PTO = c1.FK_PTO
  and c2.ID <= c1.ID
group by c1.ID;
```

Result:

```
| ID | FK_PTO | NUM | HORA | rank |
|----|--------|-----|------|------|
| 55 |    122 | 566 | 5:02 |    1 |
| 56 |    104 | 568 | 5:16 |    1 |
| 57 |    114 | 572 | 5:38 |    1 |
| 58 |    104 | 573 | 6:12 |    2 |
| 59 |    110 | 577 | 6:28 |    1 |
| 60 |    122 | 582 | 6:45 |    2 |
```

And

```
select r1.*, count(*) as rank
from RUTA r1
join RUTA r2
  on  r2.FK_PTO = r1.FK_PTO
  and r2.ID <= r1.ID
group by r1.ID;
```

Result:

```
| ID | FK_RUTA | FK_PTO | TIEMPO | rank |
|----|---------|--------|--------|------|
| 15 |      56 |    122 |      0 |    1 |
| 16 |      56 |    104 |     12 |    1 |
| 17 |      56 |    114 |     22 |    1 |
| 18 |      56 |    104 |     32 |    2 |
| 19 |      56 |    121 |     40 |    1 |
| 20 |      56 |    110 |     45 |    1 |
| 21 |      56 |    122 |     55 |    2 |
```

Now you can join the two results using the generated `rank`

```
select *
from (
  select c1.*, count(*) as rank
  from PTO_CONTROL c1
  join PTO_CONTROL c2
    on  c2.FK_PTO = c1.FK_PTO
    and c2.ID <= c1.ID
  group by c1.ID
) c
join (
  select r1.*, count(*) as rank
  from RUTA r1
  join RUTA r2
    on  r2.FK_PTO = r1.FK_PTO
    and r2.ID <= r1.ID
  group by r1.ID
) r using (FK_PTO, rank)
```

Result:

```
| FK_PTO | NUM | HORA | TIEMPO |
|--------|-----|------|--------|
|    122 | 566 | 5:02 |      0 |
|    104 | 568 | 5:16 |     12 |
|    114 | 572 | 5:38 |     22 |
|    104 | 573 | 6:12 |     32 |
|    110 | 577 | 6:28 |     45 |
|    122 | 582 | 6:45 |     55 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3f427/5